# private method `open' called for #<File:arun1.txt> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

```
class Arun 
   def arun
    afile=File.new("arun1.txt")
      if afile
       afile.open("arun1.txt","w")
        afile.syswrite("hi from arunkumar.............")
       afile.close()
       afile.open("arun1.txt","r+")
        con=afile.sysread(30)

        puts con
       afile.close()
      else
        puts "can't open"
      end

    end
 end
 a=Arun.new
 a.arun
```

Here I can't access the `arun` method its shows private method `open` called for `#<File:arun1.txt>`  (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Ruby documentstion on File IO](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-write)

Specifically, in order to write to a file just use something like

```
File.open("arun.txt", 'w') {|f| f.write("hi from arunkumar.............") }
```

As your error indicates, the `open` method isn't available for an object.

Answer (score 0):

at the beginning of the program write the below given statement. As IO is a class, standing for InputOutput, containing all methods including open

require IO